# conversion of htm file into a ppt file

Tags: html, powerpoint

I need to convert a .htm file to a power point presentation(ppt) using Apache POI. But later on I realized that Apache POI can only convert raw data into a ppt. For that we have to extract the data from the htm file and correspondingly enter it to the ppt file. Can we automate that using Apache POI? so that is there any other option to convert htm file to an ppt file? please guide me.thnks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Another option for what you want to accomplish is [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/), which can convert from HTML or Markdown (among other things) to a huge variety of formats. If I recall correctly, it does not support Powerpoint, but it supports many other presentation formats, including HTML5 and PDF slides.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention POI, I assume you're interested in doing this in Java.

docx4j uses xhtmlrenderer (Flying Saucer) to convert XHTML to docx, so you could also use it to convert XHTML to pptx (in conjunction with either POI or docx4j).

But writing such a converter is not a job for the faint hearted.

Another possible approach would be to use OpenOffice/LibreOffice, but on a quick look, that works better for importing HTML into documents. See also help.libreoffice.org/Impress/Importing_HTML_Pages_Into_Presentations